Обновление данных, полученных через EventBus
Я использую библиотеку EventBus для передачи данных (позиция и длительность аудио) из сервиса с объектом Media Player'а во фрагмент, в котором этот сервис запускается.
AudioService.kt:
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    // ...
    EventBus.getDefault().post(
        PositionAndDurationData(
            mediaPlayer.duration,
            mediaPlayer.currentPosition
        )
    )
    // ...
}

AudioFragment.kt:
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // ...
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this@AudioFragment)
    // ...
}

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
fun onEvent(result: PositionAndDurationData) {
    audioDuration = result.duration
    audioPosition = result.position
}

PositionAndDurationData.kt:
data class PositionAndDurationData(
    var duration: Int,
    var position: Int,
)

Как сделать так, чтобы передаваемые в UI данные обновлялись каждую секудну?

Ну... Вам надо запустить в сервисе код, который будет раз в n времени посылать событие. Сделать такое можно многими разными способами. Даже не знаю какой вам будет проще... Попробуйте через Timer, например. Или через цикл в потоке. Или на RxJava или на корутинах

к сожалению, у MediaPlayer'а нет внутреннего колбэка, который бы возвращал вам данные про проигрываемое аудио. поэтому придется самому в бесконечном цикле проверять эти параметры. p.s. EventBus - не самая лучшая библиотека для отслеживания событий.

Решил проблему при помощи банального viewBinding'а.
В AudioFragment.kt перенёс lateinit var binding: FragmentAudioBinding в Companion Object, благодаря чему переменная стала доступна в AudioService.kt. При помощи неё можно получить доступ к элементам UI прямо из сервиса.
Метод, инициализирующий TextView с позицией и длительностью аудио, перенёс в сервис.
Таким образом, в данном случае можно обойтись без EventBus.
Предположу, что найденное мною решение небезупречно с концептуальной точки зрения, однако оно вполне рабочее.
